# Pipenv error "No Python at 'C:\Python39\python.exe' "

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I installed and added Python3.9 and Pip to the PATH through the installer.

```bash
python --version
# Python 3.9.7
pip --version
# pip 21.2.4 from C:\Users\{MyUserName}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

I installed pipenv with `pip install pipenv` and `pipenv --version` outputs `pipenv, version 2021.5.29`. Although, if I try to install any package with pipenv, or just enter the pipenv shell and then run `python --version`, I always get `No Python at 'C:\Python39\python.exe'`.

Python sys path is `C:\Users\{MyUserName}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`, so why does pipenv look into another folder? And how can I fix this?

I'm running all these commands in git bash.

Comment: Did you try `python3 --version` ?

Comment: @SarveshM.D it outputs "Python was not found". Does pipenv look for python3 path? Is that different?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For anyone running into this error, run the following to delete the virtual environment (built with the previous/future version of Python):

```bash
    cd $project_folder
    pipenv --rm
```

Then rerun this to build your pipenv virtual environment with your new version of Python:

```
pipenv install
```

Comment: I ran into this error and I can say this solution works. The reasoning is that virtual environments in python and complete python installations with their own paths. If you move them or try to use them somewhere else, they do not work. (The same happens if you change/remove the Python version they used.)

Comment: Thanks, To complement, in my case, I had to change the python_version value in my Pipfile.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem removing the "C:\Python39" from the Path (the older Python version I've deleted) and leting only the "C:\Users{MyUserName}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39" on the Path

Answer (score 2):

So I was having the same problem and I clicked at the pyvenv.cfg file in my virtual environment's folder. 'home' was C:\Program Files at default. So I changed it to the right path and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually creating `C:\Python39\` and copying `python.exe` there. Now it works fine.

Comment: Not happy of how hacky this is

Comment: I would not recommend doing this for two reasons. 1 - Having multiple same-version Python installations in different locations could create future problems. 2- This solution is a patch for the problem, rather than a real fix.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a copy of get-pip.py

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Next, run the following command to install pip:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Also, make sure you have Python in your Windows Environment Variables

Press **WIN+R** and then type **SystemPropertiesAdvanced**

In System variables add the Python path

[image]

Comment: What does it change? Also why is this so hard to find? I know it's PyPa but I've never seen any mention of `get-pip.py` elsewhere

Comment: No way this would solve the problem described in the question: Pip was already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Look for it in \AppData\Roaming\Python\PythonX\scripts

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.

I had to remove the two `C:\Python39` & `C:\Python\Scripts\` references in the PATH system environment variables.

Once i did that then i was able to run commands like normal.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to ensure in PATH, there is only the needed python, or at least it should be up comparing to unused python version.

delete C:\Users{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\pipx folder, no worry it is just cache.

delete C:\Users{USERNAME}.local\bin folder, you may need to reinstall whatever inside later.

pipx works afterwards.